# Total Documents Processed = 0 though Total Rows Fetched is non zero using Solr with Oracle database

Tags: solr

I am using dataImportHandler to import data into solr from Oracle db. Though the import and idexing is successful I am not able to search as the documents do not get created.There are no errors in the logs also.Here are my config file snippets. Kindly help.

```
<requestHandler name="/dataimport" class="org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandler"> 
    <lst name="defaults">
        <str name="config">data-config.xml</str>
    </lst> 
</requestHandler>
```

schema.xml

```
<types>
    <fieldType name="string" class="solr.StrField" sortMissingLast="true" omitNorms="true"/>
</types> 
<fields>
    <field name="eid" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" /> 
    <field name="nm" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" />
</fields>
<uniqueKey>eid</uniqueKey>
<defaultSearchField>nm</defaultSearchField>
<solrQueryParser defaultOperator="OR"/>
```

data-config.xml

```
<dataConfig>  url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@//abc"  user="abc"  password="abc" />
<document name="client">
    <entity name="org" query="select org.code ,org.name from abc org where org_name like 'BB%'">
        <field column="code" name="eid"/>
        <field column="name" name="nm" />
    </entity>
</document>
</dataConfig>
```

data import status:

```
<str name="Total Rows Fetched">64</str>
<str name="Total Documents Processed">0</str>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried debugging it with [DIH development mode](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DataImportHandler#Interactive_Development_Mode)?

Comment: Thanks Jem for the quick reply. I tried something like this http://localhost:8983/solr/dataimport?command=full-import&debug=false&commit=true if this is what you told and saw the following error at my console. 2011-12-26 08:42:24.638:WARN::/solr/dataimport java.lang.IllegalStateException: Committed at org.mortbay.jetty.Response.resetBuffer(Response.java:1023) at org.mortbay.jetty.Response.sendError(Response.java:240) .... :Committed before 500 null||org.mortbay.jetty.EofException<|?at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpGenerator.flush(HttpGenerator.java:791)

Comment: Hi. I tried again now but now i dont see the error i mentioned ablove but total documents processed still remains 0.

Comment: Its working fine for me now. Looks like the column names in data-config file should be in caps as Oracle returns it that way.

Answer (score 3):

Some ways to debug on the Solr Admin console (i.e. http://[yourhost]:8983/solr/index.html#/ ):

1. On Dataimport (http://[yourhost]:8983/solr/index.html#/dataimport/), check "Raw Status-Output" for **"Total Documents Failed"**:

   ```
     "statusMessages": {
       "Total Requests made to DataSource": "1",
       "Total Rows Fetched": "12966",
       "Total Documents Processed": "0",
       "Total Documents Skipped": "0",
       "Full Dump Started": "2016-08-08 11:15:18",
       "": "Indexing completed. Added/Updated: 0 documents. Deleted 0 documents.",
       "Committed": "2016-08-08 11:15:20",
       **"Total Documents Failed": "12966"**,
       "Time taken": "0:0:2.452"
     }
   ```
2. On the admin console, go to **"Logging"** page (http://[yourhost]:8983/solr/index.html#/~logging) to view error logs.

Answer (score 0):

Go to logs on the dashboard, it will show the status of the process

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sS81d.png)

Comment: dashboard in solr

Answer (score 0):

In data-config.xml->entity->query-> select statement, there must be "id" column i.e. uniquekey field.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue, no errors in logs, could not start debug mode (havn't done the pre-reqs ). For me:

In this project I am using a modified DIH example project. I had updated my solr-data-config.xml data import for a new query (with additional fields) and had not added the field to managed-schema. After adding the field, and restarting solr it indexed fine.

It would be nice if the error / issue was a little bit more clear in the solr interface.